# Unexpected id method behaviour

Tags: python, low-level

In simple terms, why this code returns False and not true:

```
a = 10
print(id(a) is id(a)) # why false?
```

id() returns integer, and same integer vars point to the same integer object. Why it returns false then? What is the difference with:

```
a = 10
b = 10
print(a is b) # it returns True
```

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: “and same integer vars point to the same integer object” — what makes you think that? Think about it: how would this be implemented efficiently in the Python interpreter? It would require potentially caching billions of objects … at the cost of gigabytes of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, while it is true that

```
a is a
```

`id(a)` is a large integer and does not compare by `is`

```
>>> a = 10
>>> print(id(a) is id(a))
False
>>> print(id(a),id(a))
(44337068, 44337068)
>>>
```

Check https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong for which integers compare by `is` - but remember that is an implementation detail so don't rely on it (always compare ints with `==`):

```
>>> a = 256
>>> b = 256
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b
False
```

(from ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers))

For further motivation to always use `==`, the following:

```
a = 300
b = 300
print(a is b)
print(a is 300)
def c(a): return a is 300
def d(a): return a is b
print(c(a))
print(d(a))
```

when saved to a file and run, prints `True`, `True`, `False`, and `True`...

Comment: Isn't it because the **is** operator checks whether they refer to the same object as opposed to equality? Because *44337068 is 44337068* is True.

Comment: @dan-klasson yes, but same-object is only true for small integers in Python (because they're cached). It is also true for constants (in the same expression), as you've shown, however `44337068 is 44337067+1` is False.

Comment: Funny thing, if you are using  python console:
`>>> a = 300
>>> b = 300
>>> a is b
>>> False` But if you run this using any IDE (pycharm, vsc) using same python binary as interpreter you get True. Why is that?

Comment: @PawełBąkiewicz it's "because" `is` is not defined to return equality over integers, and you're bound to get surprising results if you try. I've expanded my answer with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempted to do, for instance

```
 print(str(id(id(a))) + " " + str(id(id(a))))
In [54]: print(str(id(id(a))) + " " + str(id(id(a))))
2460780951888 2460780951888

In [55]: print(str(id(id(a))) + " " + str(id(id(a))))
2460780951472 2460780951472

In [56]: print(str(id(id(a))) + " " + str(id(id(a))))
2460782062320 2460782062320

In [57]: print(str(id(id(a))) + " " + str(id(id(a))))
2460780951888 2460780951888

In [58]: print(str(id(id(a))) + " " + str(id(id(a))))
2460782473392 2460782475664
```

that would return a new id for the large integer every time

As @thebjorn mentions, large integers are not cached by the python interpreter, only integers between -5 and 256 (in the CPython implementation) remain alive at all times.

Every time a large integer is reference a new object is created for it whereas for a small integer the same object keeps on being used (as an optimization) however this is not guaranteed to remain true on all python implementations.